# How to Manage Multiple Gmail Accounts on the Same PC/Browser?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-multi-login

I have a Gmail address with my employer, a personal Gmail address, and a Gmail address for my personal business.  My girfriend also has a Gmail address she uses on the same PC. Currently this requires much logging in/out to switch between everything because besides Gmail I use Google Docs, App Engine, and other sites that use the same credentials.

Is there a way to keep all of these accounts open in the same browser at the same time without constantly having to log in/out?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:** As [palms mentioned](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3608/207), this is [built into Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html) now.

Below is the original answer for reference...

---

I believe you have to use a browser extension for that. (**Update**: As some people have mentioned, this feature is [coming soon](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/07/google-tests-multiple-accounts-sign-in.html).)

**Firefox Extensions:**

- [MultiFox extension](http://br.mozdev.org/multifox/)
- [Gmail Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1320)
- [CookiePie](http://www.nektra.com/products/cookiepie-tab-firefox-extension)
- [Gmail Notifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/173/)
- [Google Account Multi-Login](http://www.worthawow.com/multiple-gmail-login-switcher/) (requires [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/748))

I think MultiFox is exactly what you want and the simplest to use. There's a [great tutorial on how to use](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/10194/sign-into-multiple-same-service-accounts-in-firefox/) it too.

**Chrome Extensions:**

- [Google Multi-Login](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hoejaanehhabnbkmbbcideapfhhbcipj)

Comment: From the Google Multi-Login page: "*Sorry, but it works on all Google Services EXCEPT GMail, Google Reader, and Google Pages!*"

The developer claims to be fixing it, but there are comments from 3 months ago saying it's not working, so who knows when it will be fixed.  Very neat concept, though.

Comment: As mentioned, the **Google Multi-login** extension doesn't work any more, and nowhere on the **Google Mail Checker Plus** or **Dayhiker** extenions does it say anything about being able to use multiple accounts - is there any documentation or explanation of how this feature is accomplished in those two Chrome addons? The Firefox addons you suggested are nice.

Comment: @tobeannounced: You're right, I removed them. I misread [life hacker's article](http://lifehacker.com/5445690/make-the-most-of-chrome-with-these-13-excellent-extensions).

Comment: Just read today this is something Google is working on on their own http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/07/google-tests-multiple-accounts-sign-in.html

Comment: -1 At this time this answer is obsolete.

Answer (score 10):

This feature was incorporated into [Gmail itself](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/access-two-gmail-accounts-at-once-in.html) after the other answers were written:

> Now, you can visit google.com/accounts and click the link next to "Multiple sign-in." After you sign into your first account, you can sign in with up to two additional accounts from the new accounts menu in the upper right hand corner of Gmail, then easily toggle back and forth between them. You can even open multiple Gmail tabs — one for each of your accounts.

Answer (score 3):

If you use Google Chrome, it now has support for multiple user profiles. Create a profile for your girlfriend and one for yourself by clicking the wrench icon and choosing Settings.

Now, you can log in to Gmail with your profile. When your girlfriend uses the computer, she can switch to her own profile by pressing `Shift-Ctrl-M`, and log in to her Gmail account.

See http://9to5google.com/2011/12/13/google-updates-chrome-with-multiple-user-profiles/ for a more thorough explanation.

Answer (score 2):

My wife come up with a very easy answer..

> One of us always uses Firefox for
>   gmail/facebook/etc the other uses IE

(It is a lot quicker the switching logins on windows when we wish to quickly check our email)

Comment: My wife and I do the same thing. Dibs on Chrome!

Answer (score 1):

I forward all my Gmail accounts (work, personal, and a few others) to a single primary Gmail account, that automatically tags incoming forwarded emails with a label defining what they're relating to (eg, did it come through my work Gmail, or my personal one... etc)

Comment: This is what I do also, forwarding + label is really useful

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1. If you use linux, you can start the same browser under multiple usernames, and these can open various gmail accounts simultaneously. I suppose same can be done with Windows too. Use multiple user accounts is one solution.

Solution 2. Use google chrome and open a new incognito window and login in your gf's name. This is an excellent solution; the only side effect is that incognito would not remember your username/password.

Solution 3. Use the [gmail multilogin extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/hoejaanehhabnbkmbbcideapfhhbcipj?hl=en) for Chrome.

Comment: Regarding solution 2:  In addition to Chrome's "Incognito Window", Firefox and Safari have "Private Browsing", Internet Explorer has "InPrivate Browsing", and Opera has "Private Tab".

Comment: Chrome's incognito window only lets you do 1 extra session. If you open a 2nd incognito window, it shares active cookies with the first, so is still logged in to that account. It's a fine solution if you only have 2 total accounts, but for more than that, it won't work. I'm not sure if IE/FF/etc are the same.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be use Gmail's IMAP services to download the mail to the email client of your choice:
Outlook, Apple Mail, Thunderbird.

Comment: The very reason why I like webmail in general and gmail in particular is because it allows me to get rid of the desktop email clients.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are great. I personally use the Google Mail Checker Plus extension for Chrome and it works just fine.

Only for the sake of completion, there is another option (which needs some more tackling): using different browser profiles in different windows.

In Firefox, you can do that by running it appending a -P to a shortcut. You can read more about it [in an old LH's post](http://lifehacker.com/231646/geek-to-live--manage-multiple-firefox-profiles).