# Is it possible to access multiple Gmail accounts concurrently?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

> **Related:**
>   [How to Manage Multiple Gmail Accounts on the Same PC/Browser?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-manage-multiple-gmail-accounts-on-the-same-pc-browser)

I used to be able to access my primary Gmail account, as well as two Google Apps accounts concurrently in the same browser as separate tabs. Now, I can't do this anymore.

Is there any workaround other than using multiple browsers?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Go to account settings (it's in the top right corner of Gmail, accessible from the drop down menu), and turn on "Multiple sign-in". You might need to do this for every account.

Comment: I saw this. Even you do this, you still have to switch among multiple accounts and won't be able to access them concurrently, right?

Comment: I have my me@gmail.com email open in one tab, and multiple me@mydomain1.com, me@mydomain2.com, me@mydomain3.com (which use Google apps) in other tabs, all concurrently. If you have multiple @gmail.com accounts, it may not work.

Comment: After more testing I realized that this actually works.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest work around is probably to use private mode browsing. I am *not* sure if you can do three accounts at one time though.

An alternative could be to just have the other accounts forward to your main accounts.

Answer (score 2):

When I need multiple accounts open simultaneously I generally open an Incognito window in Chrome. I don't know if it's possible to do three accounts at once as I only have 2 (work+personal).

Answer (score 1):

Once you allow "Multiple sign-in" you will have a "Switch account" entry in the menu that opens under the email address in the top right corner (with Account settings etc). Through this option you can simultaneously access other Gmail accounts (for which you also enabled multiple sign-ins) either as delegated or by signing in to another account.
See [Enabling multiple sign-in](http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=181599) on Google Accounts Help.