# Using multiple Google accounts without logging in and out to use

Tags: google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Manage Multiple GMail Accounts on the Same PC/Browser?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3423/how-to-manage-multiple-gmail-accounts-on-the-same-pc-browser)

How do I set up multiple Google accounts so that I do not have to log out one to log in to the other?

I need both open for my work and would like to know if it's possible to be logged into more than one simultaneously.

Comment: Do you already have two accounts registered? Are you asking how to add them to Google Chrome?

Comment: see [Is it possible to access multiple Gmail accounts concurrently?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/16074/is-it-possible-to-access-multiple-gmail-accounts-concurrently)

Answer (score 3):

You can open up a secondary account in your browser's private browsing mode.

- Ctrl+shift+n [in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95464&p=cpn_incognito)
- Ctrl+shift+p [in Firefox](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-browse-web-without-saving-info#w_how-do-i-turn-on-private-browsing)
- Choose Private browsing from the main menu [in Safari](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5000).
- Ctrl+shift+p [in Internet Explorer](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH5000) (>= 8).

Answer (score 0):

See the following google answer:

https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1721977

I use multiple accounts and it works great.  Another nice feature is to pin the gmail tabs (if you use chrome), and use the unread count in tab title lab.

Comment: Please provide more information to your answer, then just providing a link.  Answers should still be useful even when or if a link dies.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to logout from your gmail account, you can see the option Add account beside the sign out option. Click on it and just follow the rest. Its easy to setup.