# How do I get my own Gmail account on my laptop?

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-multi-login

Want to open in my Gmail email account, but can't.

I've set up a new Gmail account for a friend on my computer and now every time I go to my Gmail account, my friend's login details come up instead.

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/3608) to that question, as I updated it with the current information.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will save login data for anyone that has logged into a Gmail account. Either one of two ways to get rid of this.

1. Click 'Sign in with a different account', click Remove and select your friend's account to delete.
2. Clear your browser's cache and cookies.